# how to pick up multiple coins with Phaser?

Tags: phaser

I have a function that drops coins but I can only pick them up one by one when I click on them. Is it possible to make it so that I can pick up anything that overlaps?

```
dropCoins: function() {
var coinsNumber = 3;
for (var i = 0; i < coinsNumber; i++) {
  var coin = this.coins.getFirstDead();
  coin.body.collideWorldBounds = true;
  coin.anchor.setTo(0.5, 1);
  coin.reset(this.enemy.x, this.enemy.y - this.enemy.height / 2);
  game.physics.arcade.enable(coin);
  coin.body.bounce.set(0.3);
  coin.body.drag.set(80);
  coin.body.gravity.y = 1500;
  coin.body.velocity.y = -500;
  coin.body.velocity.x = Math.random() * 150 * util.plusOrMinus();
  coin.gold = Math.ceil( game.global.enemyHPTotal * (0.02 + (0.00045 * Math.min(game.global.level, 150))) );
  game.time.events.add(3000, this.removeCoin, this, coin);
}
this.coins.setAll('inputEnabled', true);
this.coins.callAll('events.onInputDown.add', 'events.onInputDown', this.removeCoin);
```

},

any help is appreciated. thanks

Comment: You can set an area around the clicked coordinates and check if any coins coordinates are inside that zone

Comment: can you show me how to do that?

Comment: In a nutshell, you need to calculate distance between click coordinates and coordinates of coin center and if it is lower than some predefined value (say 10 units), you pick up this coin. Also i need to add that calculating distance a lot of times per frame can really slow your game down. That's because to calculate distance you need to find square root which is performance-intensive operation. To avoid this instead of calculating distance calculate squared distance. I'm not adding any code here, squared distance formula is `(x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2`.